# How to retrieve the filename of an image with keras flow_from_directory shuffled method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, generator, keras

If I don't shuffle my files, I can get the file names with `generator.filenames`. But when the generator shuffles the images, filenames isn't shuffled, so I don't know how to get the file names back.

Comment: It would be very useful to be able to get the filenames in the same order as the generator, regardless of whether using shuffle. After training, I like to try to understand what my models are 'seeing' by looking at images where there were false positives, true positives, etc. It would be simpler and less expensive to use the filenames from the training generator for this, but right now the only way I can figure out to do this is create a separate 'evaluate' generator which has shuffle=False.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, the `DirectoryIterator` will iterate over an `index_arrray` which is shuffled when you ask it to.

You just need to index the filename array using the current indexes of the batch:

```
it = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(shuffle=True,...)
for img in it:
    idx = (it.batch_index - 1) * it.batch_size
    fnames = [it.filenames[it.index_array[i]] for i in range(idx, idx + it.batch_size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option here is to NOT shuffle the files. I have been wondering this myself and this is the only thing I could find in the docs. Seems odd and not correct...